# I am trying to create a Python script so I can read an image for specific blocks on a ticket to ride map and get the central coordinates and degrees

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJnlA.jpg)

This is the exact image that I will use for it. It has all these little route blocks at specific coordinates and all of them have a specific angle. What I want to try and get is the central coordinates and the degrees of the angle the block is looking at. Is this something that would be possible with Python? My experience with Python is not good enough to find a solution for this myself.

I've tried working with contours and finding the central coordinates of the blocks this way and this works for some but has a lot of misses and some odd extras that it finds. I am at a loss of how I would solve this. Thanks in advance for helping!